# My murmur (mumble server) periodically disconnects every user. "Disconnecting Ghost"

Tags: networking, mumble

Murmur is running on Mac OS and has been working fine for over a year now. I came back from a three week vacation and whenever someone is connected they will get be shortly (but not instantly ~ 30 secs) disconnected. In the server log it says "disconnecting ghost".

I have completely deleted and reinstalled all the mumble server files. So the current server is a completely fresh version downloaded from the site. I have also updated my client to the most recent version.

I have checked all the port forwarding and address assigning (for the server) and it seems fine.

It only ever sees light traffic less than 10 users and it does it for every person on the server.

I do not know what else to say so if I haven't given important information please ask.

```
  <W>2015-07-11 18:27:33.048 Connection: Failed to set TOS for TCP Socket
<W>2015-07-11 18:27:33.097 1 => <39:(-1)> Client version 1.2.10 (Win: 1.2.10)
<W>2015-07-11 18:27:33.100 1 => <39:Blue0ak(1)> Disconnecting ghost
<W>2015-07-11 18:27:33.102 1 => <38:Blue0ak(1)> Connection closed:  [-1]
<W>2015-07-11 18:27:33.106 1 => <39:Blue0ak(1)> Authenticated
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.866 1 => <40:(-1)> New connection: [fe80::9132:4cde:8c1f:7136]:59184
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.867 Connection: Failed to set TOS for TCP Socket
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.925 1 => <40:(-1)> Client version 1.2.10 (Win: 1.2.10)
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.929 1 => <40:Blue0ak(1)> Disconnecting ghost
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.942 1 => <39:Blue0ak(1)> Connection closed:  [-1]
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:01.947 1 => <40:Blue0ak(1)> Authenticated
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:10.924 1 => <40:Blue0ak(1)> Connection closed: The remote host closed the connection [1]
<W>2015-07-11 18:29:10.926 1 => Ending voice thread
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The server was falling asleep. When the server went into sleep mode it probably closed some network connections which prevented murmur from receiving packets from users. The murmur server would then consider that user a ghost and disconnect them.

I was able to disable the server's sleep timer. And now the problem is gone.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little?

Comment: Is this answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

How did you disable the servers sleep timer?

I had thought the same thing, so I verified that the network adapter was always awake (on) and that the system power settings were set to turn monitor off after 3 minutes, never turn the hard drives off and never go to standby or hibernate.

Sorry, I could not add this as a comment, since i do not have 50 rep yet.

Comment: My server is running Mac OS X. I just went into system preferences and changed the sleep timer to infinite. It looks like you have done the equivalent in your server's operating system, but maybe research other methods for disabling its sleep timer. Furthermore, there are other issues that may cause this "ghosting issue" and the sleep timer may not be yours.

Comment: So you actually told the computer that mummur is running on, to never put your NIC into power saving sleep mode.  I did that also.  Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still exists.  I did notice, that the issue started after updating the murmur server software.  I believe going by memory, the last version I used with no issues was v1.2.4. or earlier.  One thing I did do, was change the audio notifications for connected / disconnected to NO Notification.  It didn't fix the issue, but it made it less annoying.  From here I will try contacting the murmur dev team.  (had to add as comment, the edit timer wouldn't allow me to edit after the info was typed)